# I want to know the sample bucket name in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im new for AWS and im using boto3 for uploading files to s3. But im bit confused in configuring boto3 connection. Below is the code.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id='access_key',
    aws_secret_access_key='secret_key'
)

data = open('test.txt', 'rb')
s3.Bucket('bucketname').put_object(Key='test.txt', Body=data)

I tried to print the bucket names using below code and it worked well.

for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

But if i give the bucketname in
`s3.Bucket('xxxxxx').put_object(Key='test.txt', Body=data)`

im getting error as:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name "xxxxxx": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$"
```

I need help on this.

Comment: Like the error said, you gave a bucket name that is not valid. Bucket names must be up to 255 characters long and can only have English letters, numbers, periods, hyphens and underscores. I assume that `'bucketname'` and `'xxxxxx'` are placeholders for the actual value that you are passing, so I can't tell what's wrong with it, but if you are printing the names of your buckets you should be able to use any in that list.

Answer (score 14):

If you bucket is `s3://my-bucket-x/`, then use `my-bucket-x` for the bucket name in `boto3`.

Answer (score 3):

From exception it seems Bucket Name you are passing is not following S3 Bucket Name restrictions.

[Rules for S3 Bucket name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html)

From above link:

> The rules for DNS-compliant bucket names are as follows:
>
> •Bucket names must be at least 3 and no more than 63 characters long.
>
> •Bucket names must be a series of one or more labels. Adjacent labels
>   are separated by a single period (.). Bucket names can contain
>   lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens. Each label must start and end
>   with a lowercase letter or a number.
>
> •Bucket names must not be formatted as an IP address (for example,
>   192.168.5.4).

Also...

> Important
>
> On March 1, 2018, we are updating our naming conventions for S3
>   buckets in the US East (N. Virginia) Region to match the naming
>   conventions we use in all other worldwide AWS Regions. After this
>   date, Amazon S3 will no longer support creating bucket names that
>   contain uppercase letters or underscores. This change ensures that
>   each bucket can be addressed using virtual host style addressing, such
>   as https://myawsbucket.s3.amazonaws.com. We highly recommend that you
>   review your existing bucket-creation processes to ensure your
>   adherence to our DNS-compliant naming conventions.